# How can I install ASIO4ALL on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, sound, external-soundcard

I need to install ASIO4ALL.

I need this program for producing music in Ableton. I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

A forum from a Google search had this post:

> Linux already has a low latency kernel, so no need for Asio4All... Check planet ccrma to get the updated kernel if needed (RPM).. and as posted before, Jack is needed.. as an aside, check out Ardour or Audacity

And also this:

> What you are looking for is [wineasio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wineasio/). This allows Windows programs to see the jack server as an asio device.
>
> I was able to run Ableton Live 7, Reaper and all my vst(i) plugins almost flawlessly.
> But i have more xruns than with asio4all on Windows when using softsynths at the same latency (256p/f => 10ms). I believe this has more to do with wine task scheduling, as it seems highly related to gui interaction.

So I advise you either use the source forge project, or use another program, like audacity, rather than Ableton.

<sup>[Source](http://mtippach.proboards.com/thread/1533/linux-driver)</sup>

Comment: I've tried to do wineaiso, and it requires `asio.h` from "Steinberg's ASIO SDK" the download requires a developer account. http://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developers.html

Comment: However, I've never been able to successfully register for a dev account, and I think the required version of the SDK is not available there, so this link has a "link" to direct download ;) https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/steinberg-asio/

Comment: @mateo I just downloaded it from sourceforge. I have no account. Try audacity if you cant.

Comment: @Tim that is what I was trying to say "wineaiso" requires an extra file not included in the sourceforge download

Comment: @mateo ahh okay then.

Comment: Another good program is Ardour.